# Exchange 2013 ECP looping to login page

Tags: exchange, windows-server-2012, spam-prevention, outlook-web-access

I have successfully installed Exchange 2013 on my Windows 2012 Server. Everything is set up, and things are working just fine. Until just a bit ago I tried logging into the management console ECP within the outlook web app using my Administrator account. However I am constantly looped back to the login screen with no error message at all when I access my domain.com/ecp. OWA works like a charm when logging in with Admin and the credentials, just the admin website ECP wont work.

Nothing changes when using Safari instead of Chrome or when trying it locally on the server with localhost/ecp and Internet Explorer.

I cant think of what I might have changed or broken. I did install ORF antispam trial, which could have coincided or maybe it is the ongoing migration of accounts with MigrationWiz ... none of these make any sense to me, however I really need ECP obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Have you setup the redirects yet?

If the ECP container hasn't been setup properly in IIS, then you will get kicked like that. It may be that you are getting redirected, (and that would also explain no errors in the event logs).
If you do have it setup, then you would access it using https, as in:
"https://mail.domain.com/ecp". Is that how you are attempting to access it?

If you do have IIS setup, and you are still getting kicked, then I would suggest you run through the entire procedure to set it up again.  And before you un-check the box that says "Redirect requests to this destination", make sure the line that contains the destination is completely blanked out. I have seen peculiar behavior even with the box unchecked, so make sure that there is nothing in there.

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same issue with IE10. I used Chrome with the exact same credentials & all works fine...the only difference I can see is that IE is set to open in "new tab" & Chrome is set to open in "new window".

Answer (score -1):

Check the ip restriction on a ecp under default website,if you use some allowed ip white list all other will be redirected to owa login page..